# Wifi only working on laptop, not connecting on android/chromebook

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, android

I googled, I searched this forum, I didn't come up with anything that matches or helps.

My girlfriend and I were watching a TV show online on her chromebook, everything was working fine. When the episode ended I closed the tab and tried to open a tab with the new episode and it said no connection. I opened up the wifi settings on the chromebook and tried to re-connect. It asked for a password, which made me think that the password on the network had been changed by the less-than-pleasant woman who lives downstairs and controls the router. When the connection failed, the popup in the bottom corner said the network was out of range. So I tried my phone (android) (which is always connected to this network when I'm home) and it wasn't connected, nor was my girlfriend's (also android). I opened the wifi settings on the phone and forgot the network, then scanned. IT showed up, but when I try to connect it just says "connecting" for a minute then gives up and shows the network as "saved, secured with wpa2", as though I were not in range. Same with my girlfriend's phone.

Here's the really weird thing though: the lady that lives downstairs isn't home, hasn't been home since the wifi was working on all devices, and, weirdest of all: I'm posting this from a windows 7 laptop connected to the same network, in the same room as the 3 devices that won't connect. I haven't tried restarting the laptop to force a reconnect, but I'm taking the fact that it hasn't disconnected as a weird indication of...something. I don't know.

I haven't encountered this before, so I haven't the foggiest idea what to do. And before anyone suggests it, I tried loading up the router's setting page, 192.168.1.1. I can ping it from command prompt, but it won't load in a browser. I gave it 5 minutes in 2 different browsers, it just says "waiting for 192.168.1.1" forever. Oh, and I don't have physical access to the router either, that's in less-than-pleasant's room.

Answer (score 0):

restart your router, that's only thing you can do while the lady is not home.

probably you need to switch off main electricity switch, I believe that's only thing you can do, once she is there, you can come back here with more details,

your router model / channel configuration? so that it does not happen again, at least when the lady is out.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I don't have access to the breaker box, or downstairs where the router is, at least not until she gets home. And as far as I can tell (from never having actually seen the physical router, but having accessed the settings page), it's a linksys wrt54g or similar.

Comment: nah, as you don't have access to physical router / settings page, it's better to wait for the lady to get back. Or if you can, try connecting ethernet cable.

Comment: I ended up moving the modem and router to an upstairs room, so I have access to it all the time. I'm gonna make that room my computer room as well, so it's all good.